# I need help compiling the linux kernel for WM8650 (armv5te)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, arm

I have a cheap laptop that uses the WonderMedia 8650 CPU. It has 256MB of DDR3 ram and 4GB of on-board NAND FLASH. This laptop comes with android 2.2 from the factory. Even when it was released, it was pretty useless. Later on they started shipping it with WindowsCE.

The thing is that I've found out there was a [git](https://github.com/linux-wmt/linux-vtwm) with all the necessary to build the linux kernel. Sadly, its not the newest kernel, not even the stable, its Linux 3.13-rc8. Despite that, I want to give it a try, but I'm completely lost on where to start. The wiki on the github page has a "[Build the source](https://github.com/linux-wmt/linux-vtwm/wiki/Build-the-source)" title, but I cannot get over step 2 because of this errors:

```
fpp@FPP-PC:~/Documentos/linux-vtwm$ make ARCH=arm zImage
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-mabi=aapcs-linux’
gcc: note: valid arguments to ‘-mabi=’ are: ms sysv
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mlittle-endian’
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mapcs’
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mno-sched-prolog’
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mno-thumb-interwork’
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mfpu=vfp’
make[1]: *** [Kbuild:21: kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1064: prepare0] Error 2
```

I dont really know much about compiling the linux kernel, but I've followed many different "Build your own linux kernel" guides (for x86), and I think I'm somewhat familiarized with the process, but I dont know what to do when i stubmle

Comment: Usually, when you tell your package manager to "install development tools", you'll only get the development tools for your *local system architecture*, e.g. x86_64 for modern 64-bit PCs. If you are preparing to build a Linux kernel for ARM on a x86 system, you'll need to install additional *cross-development tools* packages for the ARM architecture. It seems you either don't have those installed yet, or aren't invoking the ARM crossbuild version of the `gcc` compiler (if your distribution packages it as a separate compiler binary).

Comment: Having said that, if there is no ready-made distribution to install on your ARM laptop, building the kernel is just the first step on a long road. You might have to build your system [Linux From Scratch-style](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). In particular, you might want to read the [book being produced by the ARM fork of the LFS project](https://github.com/cross-lfs/lfs-arm) to get an overview ot the task and a lot of good advice.